# Get number filtering criteria from cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, filtering, excel-2016

I am using Excel 2016.

Currently, I have a column `C` of numeric data which has a number filter where `column data > 2` are filtered.

Instead of clicking the filter icon to set the number filter, I would like to put this criteria into a cell. For example, if cell `A2` contains `3`, `column data > 3` in column `C` will be filtered.

Can this be done in Excel? I am open to using VBA to solve this problem.

Comment: Can this be done in Excel : Yes ; Without VBA : Unlikely

Answer (score 2):

A VBA easy solution:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Range("C1").AutoFilter 1, ">" & Target, xlFilterValues
    End If
End Sub
```

To be inserted in the sheet code with a change event:

[image]

[image]

Note: I set the reference cell as "A1" to avoid it being hidden by the filter.